# solving second order non-homogeneous differential equation 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me to solve this  non-homogeneous differential equation :

$
y''+y=\tan x
$

$
0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$

I could reach to $y_{c}=c_{1}\cos x + c_{2}\sin x$ but particular solution is where I stopped.

Comment: this will help you

Comment: I think you mean "particular solution" :) What methods do you have for nonhomogeneous ODEs? Do you know variation of parameters?

Comment: @GPerez: excuse me because of my mistake...yes I know variation of parameter.in fact my problem is solving $u1=\int{\dfrac{-y_{2}*f(x)}{w(y_{1},y_{2})}}$ I also found $w(y_{1},y_{2})=1$ but something doesn't right when I move forward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing a solution of the homogeneous ODE, for example $c\cos(x)$, remplace the constant $c$ by a function $Y(x)$ , i.e.: change of function $y=Y(x)\cos(x)$. This allows to reduce the second order ODE to a first order ODE easier to solve.

[image]